# Accessing the common entity properties in Inheriting Class in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

> I am implementing [repository model](http://code.google.com/p/nhibernate-repository-example/) for fluent nhibernate.
>
> My project has the following structure

```
    public interface IRepository<T>
    {

    #region Create Methods 1

        /// <summary>
        /// This method Submits the Bonus Offer to the database.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Value">Type of Bonus Subject Eg. Bonus1, Bonus2, Bonus3, Bonus4 </param>
        void SubmitPost(T Value);

        #endregion

        #region Read Methods 4

        /// <summary>
        /// This method retrieves the Bonus offers not older than a month.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns a List of Type T which is collection of particular type of Bonus Subject Eg. Bonus1, Bonus2, Bonus3, Bonus4</returns>
        IList<T> GetPostsNotOlderThan30Days();

        /// <summary>
        /// This method returns the most recent 10 posts.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns a List of Type T which contains a collection of Bonus offers which are the top 10 recently posted ones.</returns>
        IList<T> GetRecent10Posts();

        /// <summary>
        /// This method returns a Bonus Subject given its matching Id Provided.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Id">Id of the Bonus Subject of Type T. Eg. If of any of the Bonus1, Bonus2, Bonus3, Bonus4 Subjects.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        T GetPostById(object Id);

        /// <summary>
        /// This method returns all the Bonus offers of any Particular Bonus Subject posted by a particular user.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="UserId">Logged In UserId</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        IList<T> GetUserPosts(object UserId);
        #endregion
    }
```

> ```
>  and I have 4 Bonus Types
>     namely Bonus1, Bonus2, Bonus3, Bonus4
>     All these have some common properties like DateUpdated, DateExpires.
>
>     And when I wanted to implement the class for IRepository which is BonusRepository
> ```

```
    public class BonusRepository<T>:IRepository<T> where T:class
        {
            protected Configuration config;
            protected ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

            public BonusRepository(string conStr)
            {
                config=Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(
                        MsSqlConfiguration
                        .MsSql2008
                        .ConnectionString(conStr))
                        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<BonusRepository<T>>())
                    .BuildConfiguration();
                sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
            }

            #region Create Methods 1

            /// <summary>
            /// This method Submits the Bonus Offer to the database.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="value">Type of Bonus Subject Eg. Bonus1, Bonus2, Bonus3, Bonus4</param>
            public void SubmitPost(T value)
            {
                using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
                using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Save(value);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region Read Methods 4

            /// <summary>
            /// This method retrieves the Bonus offers not older than a month.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>Returns a List of Type T which is collection of particular type of Bonus Subject Eg. Bonus1, Bonus2, Bonus3, Bonus4</returns>
            public IList<T> GetPostsNotOlderThan30Days()
            {
                using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
                using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                  //Here I'm unable to get DateUpated, DateExpires
                  IList<T> returnVal=session.QueryOver<T>()
                       .Where(c=>c.

                }
            }
    }
```

> while I'm also having classes like below Bonus1Repository:
>   BonusRepository, IRepository Bonus2Repository:
>   BonusRepository, IRepository Bonus3Repository:
>   BonusRepository, IRepository Bonus4Repository:
>   BonusRepository, IRepository but as the desired functionality
>   is same across all the entites I wanted to implement in BonusRepositry
>   class iteslf. What is the best approach for this ? Can anyone suggest
>   the solution for this?
>
> Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any additional functionality in your Bonus1Repository, Bonus2Repository, etc. that you don't have in your base BonusRepository?

Comment: no additional functionality. They just represent different types like Suject as Bonus and Mathematics, Physics, Chemistry as Bonus1, Bonus2, Bonus3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can create an interface for your bonus entities that specifies the common members.  E.g.

```
public interface IBonus
{
    string GetBonusValue();
    DateTime DateUpdated{ get; set; }
}
```

and then constrain your BonusRepository using the `IBonus` interface.  E.g.

```
public class BonusRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IBonus
```

This will give you access to the `IBonus` members from your `BonusRepository<T>` generic class.

Comment: The problem is not with maintenance or non maintenance of isolated repositories. I want to access the Entity properties in the BonusRepository Generic Class. And that is not possible for me. Hence I'm here for alternative suggestions instead of writing GetPostsNotOlderThan30Days() method in each of the bonus1,2 class.

Comment: Seems some what cool but le'me give a try on this. Actually you have mentioned GetBonusValue() which is a method, But I've properties that are common in all the 4 bonus entities. like `public virtual DateTime DateUpdated{get;set;}` in all the 4 entites. So I think these can't be written as Interface members.

Comment: Actually, properties can be added to your interface.  I updated the answer.

Comment: But I'm already referencing the Type T for my class as follows `public class BonusRepository<T>:IRepository<T> where T:class` When I added like this `public class BonusRepository<T>:IRepository<T> where T:class, IRepository<T> where T : IBonus` It is throwing error ** A constraint clause has already been specified for type parameter 'T'. All of the constraints for a type parameter must be specified in a single where clause.**

Comment: Just separate your constraints with commas. I've Updated answer again.